# Use NuGet build tool packages with ASP.NET Core

Tags: msbuild, nuget, .net-core, build-tools

NuGet has several packages designed for use at build time. An example is [Google.Protobuf.Tools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Protobuf.Tools/), which contains `protoc.exe`.

With the .csproj system before .NET Core, you could add Google.Protobuf.Tools, and then use a pre-build event to run `..\Packages\...\protoc ...`.

With the new .NET Core .csproj system, in some ways it's nicer. For example, the .csproj file is cleaned up, so you can easily hand-add a build target to get incremental builds, like this:

```xml
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <CallTarget Targets="DeviceMessages" />
</Target>

<Target Name="DeviceMessages" Inputs="DeviceMessages.proto" Outputs="obj\DeviceMessages.cs">
  <Exec Command="..\Packages\Google.Protobuf.Tools.3.4.0\tools\windows_x64\protoc --proto_path=. --csharp_out=obj DeviceMessages.proto" Outputs="obj\DeviceMessages.cs" />
</Target>
```

The problem is there is no more `Packages` folder. In general, that's a good thing. But how can I get the path to just the NuGet build tool package I want, for use in a MSBuild target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a ASP.NET Core project you could use the **$(NuGetPackageRoot)** MSBuild property. This is defined after a restore in the generated obj/ProjectName.csproj.nuget.g.props file.

Then your Exec would be:

```
<Exec Command="$(NuGetPackageRoot)Google.Protobuf.Tools.3.4.0\tools\windows_x64\protoc --proto_path=. --csharp_out=obj DeviceMessages.proto" Outputs="obj\DeviceMessages.cs" />
```